# sbt 1.2.8 throwing error in non sudo mode (fedora)

Tags: scala, sbt, fedora

I have installed sbt 1.2.8 on fedora 29 following this instruction:
https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Linux.html

When I run sbt (don't matter if in project folder or any other place) I get:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)[Ljava/lang/Object;
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:74)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:56)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:18)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)[Ljava/lang/Object;
```

Running sbt with sudo privilages solves the problem. I have also tried downloading tgz package from sbt site and running

> ./bin/sbt

but with the same result (non sudo - error / sudo - everything ok).
Downgrading to 1.2.7 version also solves the problem but this is not a long term solution.

Do you have any idea what is going on ?

Comment: Do you get the same Java version under both users? `java -version`. Same question for JAVA_HOME if any

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75947449/run-a-scala-code-jar-appear-nosuchmethoderrorscala-predef-refarrayops

Answer (score 2):

It's not a particularly satisfying answer, but I was able to solve this problem (also on Fedora 29) by deleting the ~/.sbt folder

I don't know what goes on in that folder, so maybe best to make a backup first. After it was deleted, I re-ran sbt and the folder was re-appeared, but sbt no longer crashed.